# Python return statement error “ return outside function”

Tags: python

When running the following code (in Python 3.6.1)

```
def compute_cost(X, y, theta):
 m = y.size #Nombre des exemples de l'apprentissage
 predictions = X.dot(theta)
 sqErrors = (predictions - y)
 J = (1.0 / (2 * m)) * sqErrors.T.dot(sqErrors)
return J
```

I get the following error

```
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: indent your `return` so it is inside the function and not outside.

Comment: indent your `return` statement

Answer (score 3):

as I said, indent your return statement. Return must be inside your function, one level inside your def

Your code should be:

```
def compute_cost(X, y, theta):
  m = y.size #Nombre des exemples de l'apprentissage
  predictions = X.dot(theta)
  sqErrors = (predictions - y)
  J = (1.0 / (2 * m)) * sqErrors.T.dot(sqErrors)
  return J
```